# Cannot modify the private value in member function of the class

Tags: c++, function, class, private-members

I am wondering what is going on in my app.

The problem is that I cannot modify one of my private values (*temperature*) from the class *Room* while the other private one (*targetTemp*) changes without any problems.

I've got a function *setTargetTemp* where I can assign the value for *targetTemp* - works (*Room.cpp* line 18-20).
I've got another function *outsideImpact* where I can assign the value for *temperature* - doesn't work (*Room.cpp* line 21-27). The method is the same (excluding some calculations).

In *main.cpp* I called both functions (line 15 and 16) in a loop. While debugging I can see that *livingRoom's temperature* remains the same at every iteration, *targetTemp* on the other hand is changing as expected.

So what is the difference? What am I missing here?

**Room.h**

```
    class Room {
    private:
        float 
            temperature, // Temperature in the room
            targetTemp, // Target temperature in the room
            factor; // Susceptibility of the room to cooling/heating - 1 is default, +- 0.25 = ~ 1.5 C-deg / >1 - faster
    public:
        Room(void);
        ~Room(void);
        float getTemp(void);
        float getTargetTemp(void);
        void setTargetTemp(float target);
        void outsideImpact(float outsideTemp);
};
```

**Room.cpp**

```
#include "./Room.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

Room::Room(void) { 
    temperature = 15.;
    targetTemp = 22.;
    factor = 1;
}
Room::~Room(void) {}

float Room::getTemp(void) {
    return temperature;
}
float Room::getTargetTemp(void) { 
    return targetTemp; 
}
void Room::setTargetTemp(float target) { 
    targetTemp = target; 
}
void Room::outsideImpact(float outsideTemp) {
    float trendValue = (abs(temperature - outsideTemp) / 100 * factor);
    if(temperature > outsideTemp)
        temperature -= trendValue;
    else 
        temperature += trendValue;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "./Room.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    float
        timer = 0.,
        outsideTemp = -10.;

    Room livingRoom;

    do {
        timer += 0.25;
        livingRoom.outsideImpact(outsideTemp); // change the "temperature"
        livingRoom.setTargetTemp(26.+timer); // change the "targetTemp"
        cout << "Living room temp: " << livingRoom.getTemp() << " || Outside temp: " << outsideTemp
            << " || Time: " << timer << " hour(s)" << "\t|| TARGET: " << livingRoom.getTargetTemp() << endl;
    } while (round(livingRoom.getTemp()) != round(outsideTemp));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger to check the value of `trendValue` in `outsideImpact`.

Comment: Okay, now I can see it's everytime 0, but the values for the rest are:
TEMP: 15 ||  OUTSIDE: -10 ||  FACTOR: 1
Shouldn't it be trendValue = ( abs(15-(-10)) / 100 * 1) ?

Comment: It looks like you're getting the [abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) that returns an `int`, which when divided by `100` will truncate down to `0`. You can use `fabs` or `std::abs` to get the overloads that accept and return floating point values.

Comment: Omg... Totally haven't check that... Thank you for your help! Issue is solved and everybody happy :D